# Why are quotation marks showing up on certain text only in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, quotations

See this page: http://www.humanperformanceadvisors.com/Prairie/Oklahoma/Postcards/1.html

and the pages following. Why am I seeing quotation marks surrounding the product descriptions? These do not appear in Internet Explorer, only in Safari. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using the [`<q>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.2) element, which wraps its contents in quotation marks. The `<q>` element is not supported in Internet Explorer (until [IE 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304133(VS.85).aspx#Quoting) in IE 8 standards mode), so they don't show up there.